# Checking password and login validity

Tags: jquery

I use the follwoing code to check login and passowrd validity:

```
$(function (){
$('#submit').click(function(){
        var login=$('#login').val();
        var pwd=$('#pwd').val();
        if(login=='' && pwd ==''){
            $('#div').show().html("Please enter your login and password").delay(2000).fadeOut();
            return false;
        };
        if(login !='' && pwd !=''){
        var dataall={'login':login,'pwd':pwd};
        $.ajax({                                      
            url: "test.php",
            type:"POST",
            data: dataall,                                                      
            dataType: "json",                    
            success: function(data)        
            {
                var login = data[0]; 
                var password = data[1];                 
                if (login==0 || password ==0){
                 return false;
                 $('#login').val('');
                 $('#pwd').val('');
                 $('#div').show().html("The login or password is incorrect. Please try again.").delay(2000).fadeOut();
                }
            } 
        });

        }
}); 
});
```

The ajax call works well but there is problem in case login or password are wrong: the form is always submitted! even if I put `return false;`
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Move you return false statement outside your success callback. It should be at the bottom of the $('#submit').click() handler. The success callback will be called after the code for the `click()` handler have been executed.

Comment: @KristerAndersson actually it didn't work, no submit was performed!

Comment: No of course not that's because of the `return false` statement, you would also have to add something like `$('#submit').parents('form').submit()` in your success callback.

Comment: I don't understand why you like to submit the form at all. It seems like you are doing your validation through ajax in you test.php page, so when you have reached the `success` callback there should be no need to submit the form at all.

Comment: The redirection depends on submit once I test the validity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using ajax to validate the form data there should be no need to actually submit the form.

```
success: function(data) {
  var login = data[0]; 
  var password = data[1];                 
  if (login= = 0 || password == 0){
    $('#login').val('');
    $('#pwd').val('');
    $('#div').show().html("The login or password is incorrect. Please try again.").delay(2000).fadeOut();
   return;
  }
  // when you have reached this line then the user entered correct user/pass
  // if you really like the form to be submitted you could do something like this:
  $('#submit').parents('form').submit();
}
```

Like I said in my comment you should move your `return false` statement to the bottom of you `$('#submit').click()` handler to avoid the form getting submitted.

Here is a working solution:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function() {
  var login = $('#login').val();
  var pwd = $('#pwd').val();
  if (login == '' && pwd == '') {
    $('#div').show().html("Please enter your login and password").delay(2000).fadeOut();
    return false;
  };
  var dataall = {'login': login, 'pwd': pwd};
  $.ajax({                                      
    url: "form.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataall,                                                      
    dataType: "json",                    
    success: function(data) {
      var login = data[0]; 
      var password = data[1];                 
      if (login == 0 || password == 0) { 
        $('#login').val('');
        $('#pwd').val('');
        $('#div').show().html("The login or password is incorrect. Please try again.").delay(2000).fadeOut();
          return false;
        }
        $('#form').submit();
      } 
    });
    return false;
  }); 
});
```

The above code works if you add an id of `form` to your actual `form` tag and I also think you should use the most recent jQuery library for the `submit()` call to work.
Also, notice that I've changed `pw` and `log` to `password` and `login` in the `success` callback. Notice, that you will have to change the `id` of your submit button to something else than `submit`.

Comment: I want to stop submit event if the condition `log==0 || pw ==0` is true.
I put `return false;` after ajx call, the submit was stooped but if both login and password are true, submit doesn't work!

Comment: @Anibel - What didn't work? The above is not like a complete solution, it's more like showing how you can proceed, giving you a couple of hints=)

Comment: @Anibel - Also, you have an error in your `success` callback. You're checking `if(log==0 || pw==0)` which should be `if(login==0 || password==0)`

Comment: Yes I know it's not complete, let me tell you what didn't work:
when I put a `return false` after the second if, the click event doesn't work which is a good sign (in case login or pwd is wrong).
however, when login and password are true, no submission is performed.
I added this after the second if:
    `if (log==1 && pw ==1){ return true;}`
but no result.
EDIT: it's ok for `pw`, it's not the problem, it was just a mistake when copying the code

Comment: @Anibel - Now I update my answer with a complete and working solution=)

Comment: @Anibel - Did you notice that you also **must** change the `id` of your submit button to something else than `submit`?